# PostgreSQL-Data File

Tags: database, postgresql, rails-postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Which process writes the data file in PostgreSQL?

And what are the data files in postgreSQL?

Note: Performing Insert/Update/Delete operation on postgreSQL-9.5. I want to verify which Process is performing commit on Disk i.e Data File. Use of WAL and Data file.

Comment: http://www.cybertec.at/2016/11/postgresql-writer-and-wal-writer-processes-explained/ and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PostgreSQL/Architecture

Comment: Currently ,I m firing lots of queries through jmeter.checkpoint_completion_target=0.3 , checkpoint_timeout=30s, kept a delay of 30 sec between each query so that can check the data flush on data file .

Comment: For commit specifically, the backend doing the commit is what writes the WAL record marking the transaction as committed, then updates `PGPROC` to set the shared memory state. But other parts of the work done by that transaction can be written by the bgwriter, changes can be applied to the heap later by the checkpointer, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The data files of a PostgreSQL database cluster are located under the `data` subdirectory of the data directory. They are written by three processes:

- The *background writer* process that writes *dirty blocks* from the buffer back to disk to ensure that there are enough clean blocks.
- The *checkpointer process* that writes *all* dirty blocks to disk at certain times (*checkpoints*) to provide a starting point for crash recovery.
- The *backend process* (the process that serves a client connection) only writes data to disk if the background writer cannot keep up and there are not enough free blocks available.

The *write-ahead log* or WAL, located in `pg_xlog`, is something entirely different. It is written by the backend process immediately before `COMMIT` to ensure that the information necessary to recover the transaction in the case of a crash is safely written to disk. The same holds for the *commit log*, located in `pg_clog`, which contains the information if a transaction was committed or rolled back.

Data may be written to the data file before `COMMIT`, but they only become visible when the transaction is committed.

It may be worth mentioning that not only DML statements cause data blocks to be dirtied:

- The background process “autovacuum” regularly scans tables and indexes and removes unused entries.
- The first process to read newly written data will look up the commit information in the commit log and write a *hint bit* to the tuple so that future readers don't have to do that work again.

Comment: Yep. The TL;DR is "most PostgreSQL processes write to files in the data directory. Each table is one or more files, and there are other special files too. Never modify anything in the data directory except the .conf files".